# Set multiple values for a module in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to specify multiple values on the same module, but I cannot succeed. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
mod = angular.module("services", []);
mod.value("message","text1");
mod.value("message2","text2");
```

When I reference message in the HTML page it works, but when I try to use message2 it doesn't.
What's happening?

EDIT:
It worked when I changed the controller from

```
angular.module("root",["services"])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", "message", function($scope, message){
        $scope.message = message;

    }]);
```

to

```
angular.module("root",["services"])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", "message", function($scope, message){
        $scope.message = message;

    }])
    .controller("index2", ["$scope", "message2", function($scope, message2){
        $scope.message2 = message2;

    }]);
```

Comment: Are you sure to inject both Value services in the controller related to the html template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makesure to inject both Value services in the controller

controller

```
controller('Ctrl', function($scope, message, message2) {
    $scope.message = message;
    $scope.message2 = mesage2;
  })
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <p>{{message}}</p>
   <p>{{message2}}</>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't something wrong. It **[works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2YXG3/)** !
Probably some type in your code.

Make sure you inject them correctly:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, message, message2) {
    console.log(message, message2);
});
```